# include <p> content within conditional statement?

Tags: php, conditional-content

I have a gallery page wherein there are multiple individual galleries/sub-pages. I handle this function by using-

```
<?php     
    if( is_page( 39 ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=1]');
    } else {
    }
?>
```

I'm wondering, is there a way to include page specific content in that? For example, if that code is used to show A's gallery, how can I include A's bio info within that statement(using `<p>`)?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your meaning. Does `echo "<p>stuff</p>";` not work? Your shortcode is already specific to post/page 39

Comment: Sorry for not being clear; I've not worked with many conditional statements like this before.
If `echo "<p>stuff</p>";` is supposed to work, how can I include that in addition to the gallery info?

Comment: put it on the next line, you should read up on some more PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via `echo`, just place it on a new line inside the if conditionals braces `{` and `}`

e.g.

```
if(this statement is true)
{ // <- do everything between here
     /*
     stuff that happens if the statement is true
     */
} // <-- and here

else
{
     // stuff that happens if the statement is not true
}
```

So you could do this:

```
if( is_page( 39 ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=1]');
    // add more stuff here, e.g. echo "<p>Bio info etc</p>";
    echo "<p>Bio</p>";
}
```